# mysql query for two tables with left join- getting wrong results

Tags: php, mysql

I am joining two table with left join to get sum results but its giving wrong results. here is my

```
table1
    | id | event | currency | amount |
    |----|-------|----------|--------|
    | 1  | HSA   | USD      | 2000   |
    | 2  | DMME  | USD      | 3000   |
    | 3  | HSI   | INR      | 1500   |
    | 4  | HSI   | INR      | 1500   |
```

table2

```
| id | table1_id | rcvamount | adjamount |
|----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 1  | 1         | 1980      | 20        |
| 2  | 2         | 1000      | 180       |
| 3  | 2         | 1500      | 20        |
| 4  | 4         | 1487      | 13        |
```

here is my query

```
SELECT
T1.event,T1.currency,
SUM(T1.total) AS Totalvalue,

SUM(T1.received) AS Received, 
(T1.bal) AS balance
FROM (SELECT
      table1.id,
      table1.amount AS total,

      SUM(table2.rcvamount+table2.adjamount) AS received,
      ((table1.amount)- sum(table2.rcvamount+table2.adjamount)) AS bal,
      table1.event,  
      table1.currency
      FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.table1_id 
     group by table1.id)T1
      Group By T1.event,T1.currency
```

But when i run this query giving wrong results as below.when it comes to third event called HSI does not have any row for id number 3 in table2. Results should be group by event and currency.

```
| event | currency | Totalvalue | Received | balance |
|-------|----------|------------|----------|---------|
| DMME  | USD      | 3000       | 2700     | 300     |
| HSA   | USD      | 2000       | 2000     | 0       |
| HSI   | INR      | 3000       | 1500     | NULL    |
```

But actual results should be as follows

```
| event | currency | Totalvalue | Received | balance |
|-------|----------|------------|----------|---------|
| DMME  | USD      | 3000       | 2700     | 300     |
| HSA   | USD      | 2000       | 2000     | 0       |
| HSI   | INR      | 3000       | 1500     | 1500    |
```

I am not getting where my query goes wrong .Please help me to sort this.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are using `LEFT JOIN` so you will have all first table rows even they havent any match in the second table by the required join.

In your case in the first table the id=3 have no match in the second table so you get the NULL results. (`SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table1_id =3`  will give 0 results).

To avoid this use `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT T1.event, T1.currency, SUM( T1.total ) AS Totalvalue, 
       SUM( T1.received ) AS Received, ( T1.bal) AS balance
    FROM (
     SELECT table1.id, table1.amount AS total, 
     SUM( table2.rcvamount + table2.adjamount ) AS received, 
     ((table1.amount) - sum( table2.rcvamount + table2.adjamount ))AS bal,
     table1.event, table1.currency
     FROM table1
     INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
    GROUP BY table1.id
   )T1

 GROUP BY T1.event, T1.currency
```

### UPDATE :

try this ,`COALESCE()` will transform each `null` to `0`

```
SELECT T1.event, T1.currency, SUM( T1.total ) AS Totalvalue, SUM( T1.received ) AS Received, (
T1.bal
) AS balance
FROM (

SELECT table1.id, table1.amount AS total, SUM( COALESCE( table2.rcvamount, 0 ) + COALESCE( table2.adjamount, 0 ) ) AS received, (
COALESCE( table1.amount, 0 ) - sum( COALESCE( table2.rcvamount, 0 ) + COALESCE( table2.adjamount, 0 ) )
) AS bal, table1.event, table1.currency
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
GROUP BY table1.id
)T1
GROUP BY T1.event, T1.currency
```

Comment: but i want to inlcude 4th row from table1 .if i run your query it vomits the 4th row from table1 .Including 4th row for HSI event total amount is 3000 and total received amount is 1500 so balance should come as 1500..that i want with left join only..

Answer (score 0):

it will work for you

```
select tp.id,tp.event,tp.currency,
tp.totalvalue,
tr.received,
(tp.totalvalue - tr.received) AS balance
from  
(
select max(id)id,event,currency,amount,sum(amount)as totalvalue from t1
group by t1.event
)tp
inner join  
(
 select id,table1_id,rcvamount,adjamount,(sum(rcvamount) + sum(adjamount))as received
 from t2 
 group by table1_id
 order by t2.adjamount desc
)tr
 on tp.id = tr.id 
group by tp.event
```

Comment: this is giving wrong results not even close my results.

Comment: i have updated my code and its working fine.......actually previously in hurry i had copied your faulty code hence it was

Comment: You should really explain WHY you think this would work.

Comment: because i have tested it on local and its working fine

Comment: No, explain to the OP WHY it would solve their problem.